# Removing leading `# ` with awk

Tags: bash, awk

I am using the following bash function to capture lines between `## mode: rec` and `## # End of rec`, but am not able to remove the leading `#`  on the result.

```
capture ()
{
 local efile="$1"

 local begorg endorg 
 begorg='^[[:space:]]*## mode: org$'
 endorg='^[[:space:]]*## # End of org$'
 awk -v bego="$begorg" -v endo="$endorg" \
   '$0 ~ bego { flag=1; next } 
    $0 ~ endo { flag=0; } 
    flag { sub(/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*/,""); print }' "$efile"
}
```

This is the input

file: test.sh

```
## mode: org
## * Using case statement
## # End of org
case $arg in
 ("V")
   echo "Author"
   ;;
 (*)
   ## mode: org
   ## ** Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
   ## *** Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
   ## *** Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.
   ## # End of org
   break
   ;;
esac

 ## mode: org
 ## HDG: Handling function argument parsing with getopts
 ## Rmk: No call to {shift} is required with getopts
 ## Rmk: No hyphen {-} required when searching option names
 ## + Case patterns do not start with option hyphen {-} because
 ## + getopts strips off the hyphen and makes the value of {arg}
 ## + to be just the option letter.
 ## Rmk: Separating options from non-options with --
 ## + {getopts} stops processing options when the argument is not
 ## + defined as an option in {shortopts}; or if the argument is
 ## + "--", which explicitly terminates the list of options.
 ## Rmk: Using -- as value to an option
 ## + An option value can be -- without it being considered a
 ## + separator between options and non-options.
 ## + Example { edvart-getopts -g "--" }.
 ## Rmk: Explicitly testing for {--}
 ## + There is no need to test for {--} when using {getopts}.
 ## # End of org
```

But I am getting this result

```
# * Using case statement

# ** Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
# *** Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
# *** Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.

# HDG: Handling function argument parsing with getopts
# Rmk: No call to {shift} is required with getopts
# Rmk: No hyphen {-} required when searching option names
# + Case patterns do not start with option hyphen {-} because
# + getopts strips off the hyphen and makes the value of {arg}
# + to be just the option letter.
# Rmk: Separating options from non-options with --
# + {getopts} stops processing options when the argument is not
# + defined as an option in {shortopts}; or if the argument is
# + "--", which explicitly terminates the list of options.
# Rmk: Using -- as value to an option
# + An option value can be -- without it being considered a
# + separator between options and non-options.
# + Example { edvart-getopts -g "--" }.
# Rmk: Explicitly testing for {--}
# + There is no need to test for {--} when using {getopts}.
# HDG: Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
# Rmk: Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
# Rmk: Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.
```

The expected output is

```
* Using case statement
 
** Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
*** Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
*** Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.

HDG: Handling function argument parsing with getopts
Rmk: No call to {shift} is required with getopts
Rmk: No hyphen {-} required when searching option names
+ Case patterns do not start with option hyphen {-} because
+ getopts strips off the hyphen and makes the value of {arg}
+ to be just the option letter.
Rmk: Separating options from non-options with --
+ {getopts} stops processing options when the argument is not
+ defined as an option in {shortopts}; or if the argument is
+ "--", which explicitly terminates the list of options.
# Rmk: Using -- as value to an option
+ An option value can be -- without it being considered a
+ separator between options and non-options.
+ Example { edvart-getopts -g "--" }.
Rmk: Explicitly testing for {--}
+ There is no need to test for {--} when using {getopts}.
HDG: Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
Rmk: Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
Rmk: Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.
```

Comment: Add the expected output to your question.

Comment: You are not showing how you call your function.  The output that you show is clearly not the output of the code in your question given the shown `test.sh` file as input.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using the `gsub(/\s*#+\s*/,"");` [from my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372939/85695)? That produces the exact output you show since it will replace any number of `#`, but here you have changed it so that it only matches a single one (`sub(/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*/,"");`), so of course it is just removing one.

Comment: I see, so I am now using `sub(/^[[:space:]]*##[[:space:]]*/,"");` which solves the problem.

Comment: What can I do so that I can use any arbitrary comment symbol `# ; ;; ;;; ! c @c `?  I would pass the comment symbol to the function as an input parameter.

Comment: @Fatipati you could use a character class, like `[#;!c]`.

Comment: Naming a flag variable `flag` is like naming a numeric variable `number` instead of `sum`, `ave`, `tot`, `cnt`, `width`, `depth`, or whatever else it represents. Name your flag variable based on what it represents (e.g. `inBlock` or even just `f` for `found`), not the type of variable it is.

Comment: Regarding What can I do so that I can use any arbitrary comment symbol](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/675817/removing-leading-with-awk#comment1276020_675817) - ask a new question about that, it has nothing to do with this question which you already have an answer to that's waiting to be accepted, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with this command

```
awk '{sub(/^#*/,"",$0);print }' filename
```

Answer (score 4):

You are getting that result because you are explicitly instructing your program to only remove one `#`, so that is what it is doing:

```
sub(/^[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*/,"")
```

If you change that to use `#+` to remove one or more `#`, it will work as expected. Next, you want an empty line between sections, so you need an extra `print ""` when you find the end. Change your function to this:

```
capture ()
{
 local efile="$1"

 local begorg endorg 
 begorg='^[[:space:]]*## mode: org$'
 endorg='^[[:space:]]*## # End of org$'
 awk -v bego="$begorg" -v endo="$endorg" \
   '$0 ~ bego { flag=1; next } 
    $0 ~ endo { flag=0; print "" } 
    flag { sub(/^[[:space:]]*#+[[:space:]]*/,""); print }' "$efile"
}
```

The above produces:

```
$ capture file
* Using case statement

** Silent Error Reporting Mode (SERM) in getopts
*** Detects warnings without printing built-in messages.
*** Enabled by colon {:} as first character in shortopts.

HDG: Handling function argument parsing with getopts
Rmk: No call to {shift} is required with getopts
Rmk: No hyphen {-} required when searching option names
+ Case patterns do not start with option hyphen {-} because
+ getopts strips off the hyphen and makes the value of {arg}
+ to be just the option letter.
Rmk: Separating options from non-options with --
+ {getopts} stops processing options when the argument is not
+ defined as an option in {shortopts}; or if the argument is
+ "--", which explicitly terminates the list of options.
Rmk: Using -- as value to an option
+ An option value can be -- without it being considered a
+ separator between options and non-options.
+ Example { edvart-getopts -g "--" }.
Rmk: Explicitly testing for {--}
+ There is no need to test for {--} when using {getopts}.
```

Note that this doesn't keep this line commented as you have in your example output, but I am assuming that was just a mistake since there doesn't seem to be anything special about that line:

```
# Rmk: Using -- as value to an option
```

Comment: You are right, just a mistake.

Comment: @EdMorton thanks. I was pretty sure there wouldn't be, but wasn't 100% sure. How about `\s`? Are there awks that don't know how to handle `\s` and require `[[:space:]]` instead?

Comment: `\s` is a non-POSIX extension supported by GAWK but not many, if any, other awks. Maybe recent versions of mawk? Ditto for `\S` meaning `[^[:space:]]` and `\<` and `\>` for word boundaries. I actually can't think of any literal character that takes on a non-literal meaning when escaped in a POSIX ERE except common char escape sequences like `\t` and `\n`. Most ERE meta-characters become literal when escaped of course.